# CasperJS how to fire blur events

Tags: testing, phantomjs, casperjs, blur

I have a form that calculates as it is filled. I want to fill that form via casper and get the result.
In my form, I am doing the calculation on blur of each field. How can I fire a blur event using casperJS?

Comment: Are you asking how can you fire a casper event when a blur event is triggered or how to fire a blur event when a casper event is triggered? You won't need to use casper to trigger a native javascript event if you're asking how to trigger a blur event.

Comment: Either way, in my form, when a text field is blured, an ajax call is fired. I just  want to do that

Comment: @DavidKamer I am asking how to trigger a blur event when casper event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple HTML form:

```
<form id="example">
  <input name="value_one" type="text" onblur="addition()">
  <input name="value_two" type="text" onblur="addition()">
</form>
```

Let's say that the following JavaScript function is fired [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur):

```
function addition() {
  var value_one = document.getElementsByName('value_one')[0].value;
  var value_two = document.getElementsByName('value_two')[0].value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');

  result.textContent = parseInt(value_one) + parseInt(value_two);
}
```

You can use the following CasperJS script to obtain the result:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://www.example.com/', function () {
  this.fill('#example', {
    value_one: '5',
    value_two: '10',
  });

  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#result').text); // Result: 15
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: The problem here is, I am filling out the form in `Knockout`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) you can just trigger native blur function:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    document.querySelector('.some-element').blur();
});
```